# PHP shell_exec wait for script to finish?

Tags: php, queue, shell-exec

I have a PHP script that queries a database for a list of jobs to be done and fires off other PHP scripts based on what it finds in the database (basically a process queue).

Some of the scripts that the queue runner script executes may take 30 seconds or so to finish running (generating PDFs, resizing images, etc).

The problem is that `shell_exec()` in the queue runner script calls the processing scripts, but then doesn't wait for them to finish, resulting in the queue not being completed.

Queue runner script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    // Loop through database and find jobs to be done
    shell_exec(sprintf("/root/scripts/%s.php", $row['jobName']));
?>
```

Job script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    shell_exec("/usr/bin/htmldoc -t pdf --webpage test.html > test.pdf");
    // Update database to mark job as completed
?>
```

Running the job script directly from the command line works and the PDF is created.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Or a better way to run a process queue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
shell_exec("nohup /usr/bin/htmldoc -t pdf --webpage test.html > test.pdf 2>&1 &");
```